# c++ Enter press to new line

Tags: c++, line-breaks

firt of all my english is not so good i thing it will be enough. 

 Ok i have this codes and u can see the basic logic in it

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, dizi2[100], imlec=0;
    char BasilanTus; 
    BasilanTus = ' ';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish"); 
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        dizi2[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
            if (i == imlec)
            {
                cout << "--> " << dizi2[i] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    " << dizi2[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "(a veya A tuşu aşağı götürür )\n(d veya D tuşu yukarı götürür)\n(c veya C tuşu programdan çıkarır)\nOkun Yonunu Secin....:";
        cin >> BasilanTus;
        if (BasilanTus == 'a' || BasilanTus == 'A')
        {
            if (imlec > 8)
            {
                imlec = -1;
            }
            imlec = imlec + 1;
        }
        else if (BasilanTus == 'd' || BasilanTus == 'D')
        {
            if (imlec <1)
            {
                imlec = 10;
            }
            imlec = imlec - 1;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

My question is, when i write 'a' and after press enter, popped out a new line after doing cls. I dont want to show a new line. How can I do that. Thanks for reading.

Comment: "popped out a new line after doing cls", what does that mean?

Comment: I think they mean the typing of <enter> generates a new line. Not sure though?

Comment: @kenny sorry for bad define. Im saying, when write press enter after 'd' char, it return like 'd[enter]' with a new line. i dont want that a new line

Comment: and @kenny a said in the begging. my english is not so good. sorry for that

Comment: @kenny yes, generating a new line. i dont want that. it just when i press d after enter it just do to system("cls") not to show a new line after cls

Answer (score 1):

Solution is using getline

```
#include <string>

string BasilanTus;
getline(cin, BasilanTus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use an OS or platform specific function, you will have to press Enter to tell `cin` that the input is finished.

Also, try this:

```
if (std::tolower(BasilanTus) == 'a')
```

Use `std::tolower` or `std::toupper` so you only have to perform one compare.